# SQL Server 2005 returns wrong result in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I execute the following query on table `Events` where `Number` is an `int` column which is also the primary key:

```
select Max(Number) 
from events
```

And I get 52000.

Then I execute the following:

```
select Number 
from events 
where Number > 52000
```

And I get:

```
50040
50041
50042
...
```

This is obviously wrong and not what I asked for. It returns lower numbers than 52000

Is this some bug in SQL Server 2005 (9.0.5000)? Something related to `Number` being the primary key?
[image: Image showing how rows with larger value than MAX() is returned]

Comment: I did miss that.  A little early here.  My next question is how a SELECT returns numbers less than 52000 when the query is asking for greater than 52000.  That's what made me ask the string question.  Because you can get weird results when you think it is a number and it isn't.

Comment: @SteveB And let's assume it is `string`. Now do you think the query will return those results? Those numbers are still "smaller" thank 52000 even in `string` comparison.

Comment: There is no bug in MS SQL server 2005 related to an `int` column being a primary key that produces such results. However, can you change the name of the column from "Number" to anything else that is not a reserved word and try your query again? Let us know the results.

Comment: That's what is weird.  I agree.  Just looking for possible solutions and my first thought is that strings do behave differently.  I would hope that SELECT would work either way.  Just trying to help but obviously I am not.

Comment: use proper aliases on tables `events as e` and use `e.[Number]` brackets to be sure.

Comment: I don't have the possibility to change names of the columns as this is a production database. Usin alias an brackets makes no difference.

Comment: I'm having a hard time believing this is actually happening. Can you provide an [mcve] to show the issue?

Comment: Added image showing the weird result.. MAX) is around 52000 and as can be seen, 50040 is the first row.

Comment: Have you run a `DBCC CHECKTABLE` against this table? I *guess* this could be the result of some kind of corruption.

Comment: What are you expecting to return from your query - it seems a complex way to not return anything tbh.

Comment: Jon: The query in the screenshot is just showing the problem. Normally I store the last Number and then look in the table to see if there is some new rows where Number > last.

Comment: Can you post here execution plan, please? You may have corrupted database where max(number) is read from one index (corrupted index) and the rest of the query reads from another index